# объединить поля по древовидной выборке

Tags: mysql

Данным запросом, получаю дерево категорий, но есть еще столбец code, как на базе данного запроса, получить только объединенную строку code в порядке возрастания catalog_cat.id?

```
SELECT  @r AS _id,
         (
         SELECT  @r := parent_id
         FROM    catalog_cat
         WHERE   id = _id
         ) AS parent,
         @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
 FROM    (
         SELECT  @r := 7,
                 @l := 0,
                 @cl := 0
         ) vars,
         catalog_cat h
WHERE    @r <> 0
```

@Mike , спасибо за подсказку, вот готовый вариант:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code ORDER BY CAST(`_id` AS SIGNED) ASC separator '/') AS slug
    FROM
      (SELECT @r AS _id,

         (SELECT code
          FROM catalog_cat
          WHERE id = @r ) AS code,

         (SELECT @r := parent_id
          FROM catalog_cat
          WHERE id = _id ) AS parent
       FROM
         (SELECT @r := 119) vars,
            catalog_cat h
       WHERE @r <> 0 ) qi
```

Comment: джоинете этот запрос к основной таблице еще раз и получаете из нее `group_concat(code order by id)`. думаю так проще всего. или еще одним подзапросом придется code доставать, что вряд ли будет быстрее

Comment: @Mike а как указать разделители / между склейками code?

Comment: `group_concat(code order by id separator '/')`