# Как получить значение максимальной глубины дерева?

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста с запросом. Есть таблица дерева групп: id, name, uplevel. Соответсвенно в uplevel находится id родительской группы. Допустим в 1 группе есть еще 1 вложенная подгруппа, во второй глубина 5, а в третьей, всего 2. Как узнать что максимальная глубина 5? Можно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Comment: Зависит от версии MySQL. В 8.0 есть рекурсивные CTE, см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive Для версий, не поддерживающих рекурсивных CTE, решением может быть написание пользовательской функции, которая вернёт требуемые данные, организовав циклическую выборку до достижения "дна", либо хранимой процедуры, которая может быть и рекурсивной.

Comment: В текущий версиях MySQL если не процедурами/функциями, то как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634545/194569 примерно оно же в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810076/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5